# Why is this signed flag being set? Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, flags

Quick question, why is the SF being set if the number is positive?

```
mov al,124
    add al,5     ;CF=0,SF=1,ZF=0,OF=1 
                 ;Carry flag - not set (no carry out of the most significant (leftmost) bit) 
                 ;Sign flag - set (???)
                 ;Zero flag - not set (destination not zero), 
                 ;overflow flag - set (value is not in the range of signed values for a byte)
    call dumpRegs
```

Comment: You need to read about 2's complement arithmetic. Plenty of material all over the place. Long story short, the sign bit is the most significant bit, and `124+5=129` has the MSB set. Alternatively, obviously the sign bit only makes sense in signed arithmetic, and in that case the result is actually `-127` so it's negative.

Comment: @Jester You should make that an answer.

Comment: Trust me I have read tons and I'm very aware. I'm not using a signed data type though??

Comment: No this is not a duplicate, I viewed that post before this and read it in its entirety.

Comment: the resulting number is not positive.  you overflowed and wrapped around!

Comment: There is no signed and unsigned integer datatype in x86 asm.  I think [this is the best illustration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990071/sign-carry-and-overflow-flag-assembly) I will mark as duplicate if you agree.

Comment: @FlipFlopSquid Yes it is a duplicate, you just still don't understand it. As Jester suggest you should read about 2's complement.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the one @Jester posted with the clock